# Why two $scope.$apply not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic, i integrate map with source and destination fields.
I want to address text should be changed its value on marker dragend event.
i am using $apply() for it but its not working.
here is my controller script:

```
.controller('RequestForRideCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicHistory, $http, $ionicPopup, $state, $window, $compile,$timeout) {

var Slat, Slng, Dlat, Dlng;
var Slatlng, Destination;
$scope.location = {};
$scope.location1 = {};

$scope.init = function () {
  var Smarker, Dmarker;
  var flag;

  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(19.9975, 73.7898);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    mapOptions);

  var contentString = "<div><a ng-click=''>Click</a></div>";
  var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: compiled[0]
  });


navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
    $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));

    Slat = pos.coords.latitude;
    Slng = pos.coords.longitude;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Slat, Slng);
    $scope.map.setCenter(myLatlng);

    Smarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: $scope.map,
      draggable: true,
      title: 'Source',
      label: 'S'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(Smarker, 'drag', function (event) {

      var lat = document.getElementById("latbox").value = this.getPosition().lat();
      var lng = document.getElementById("lngbox").value = this.getPosition().lng();
Slatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      flag=1;
      getPosition(Slatlng, flag);
    })});


$scope.$on('destination', function (evt, value) {
    $scope.variable = value;

    var Dlat = $scope.variable.geometry.location.lat();
    var Dlng = $scope.variable.geometry.location.lng();
    var myLatlngD = new google.maps.LatLng(Dlat, Dlng);
    $scope.map.setCenter(myLatlngD);

    var Dmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlngD,
      map: $scope.map,
      draggable: true,
      title: 'Destination',
      label: 'D'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(Dmarker, 'drag', function (event) {

      var lat = document.getElementById("latbox1").value = this.getPosition().lat();
      var lng = document.getElementById("lngbox1").value = this.getPosition().lng();
      Destination = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      flag = 0;
      getPosition(Destination, flag);
    });


function getPosition(marker, flag) {
    if (flag == 1) {
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker}, function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (results[1]) {
            $scope.location.formatted_address = results[1].formatted_address;
            $timeout(function () {
              $scope.$apply(function () {
                console.log('in source');
              });
            }, 2000);
          } else {
            console.log('Location not found');
          }
        } else {
          console.log('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker}, function (results, status, element) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (results[1]) {
            $scope.location1.formatted_address = results[1].formatted_address;
            $timeout(function () {
              $scope.$apply(function () {
                console.log('in des');
              });
            }, 2000);
          } else {
            console.log('Location not found');
          }
        } else {
          console.log('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

this is my html:

```
<ion-pane>
            <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true">
            </div>
            <div id="floating-panel" style="">
                <input type="text" id="source1" placeholder="Source" location-suggestion location="location" ng-model="location.formatted_address">
            </div>
            <div id="floating-panel1" style="">
               <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Destination" location-Destination location1="location1" ng-model="location1.formatted_address">
            </div>
</ion-pane>
```

help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: What error do you get? Is it "digest already in progress"?

Comment: actually not getting any error i just want to update textbox value on marker change, but not working for destination bt working fine with source marker

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout`. setTimeout function does not trigger `$digest` cycle.